# LINQ-To-SQL and Many-To-Many Relationship Deletions

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a many-to-many relationship between two tables, let's say Friends and Foods. If a friend likes a food I stick a row into the FriendsFoods table, like this:

```
ID Friend Food
1 'Tom' 'Pizza'
```

FriendsFoods has a Primary Key 'ID', and two non-null foreign keys 'Friend' and 'Food' to the 'Friends' and 'Foods' tables, respectively.

Now suppose I have a `Friend tom` .NET object corresponding to 'Tom', and Tom no longer likes pizza (what is wrong with him?)

```
FriendsFoods ff = tom.FriendsFoods.Where(x => x.Food.Name == 'Pizza').Single();
tom.FriendsFoods.Remove(ff);
pizza.FriendsFoods.Remove(ff);
```

If I try to `SubmitChanges()` on the DataContext, I get an exception because it attempts to insert a null into the `Friend` and `Food` columns in the `FriendsFoods` table.

I'm sure I can put together some kind of convoluted logic to track changes to the `FriendsFoods` table, intercept `SubmitChanges()` calls, etc to try and get this to work the way I want, but is there a nice, clean way to remove a Many-To-Many relationship with LINQ-To-SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the database itself has `CASCADE DELETE` rules defined on the foreign keys (otherwise you're in trouble), you need to set the **Delete Rule** on each relationship in the Linq to SQL designer (or the `DeleteRule` in the `AssociationAttribute`) to `CASCADE`.

You also don't need to delete both sides of the association - one will suffice, either from `tom` or from `pizza`.

**Addendum:** [@Crispy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569119/linq-to-sql-and-mapping-table-deletions/2569479#2569479) is also correct in that the *real* attribute you care about here is the `DeleteOnNull` attribute in the child association.  **However**, the reason that you can't see this in the designer is that the designer auto-detects the value of this property based on (a) the `CASCADE` setting of the parent-to-child association, and (b) whether or not the foreign key field is nullable.  If you have a non-nullable FK with a `CASCADE DELETE` in the Linq to SQL designer, it should automatically set `DeleteOnNull = true` for the child-to-parent association and subsequently delete the record from the mapping table instead of attempting to set its associations to `NULL`.

Comment: Won't this just delete both 'Tom' and 'Pizza' entities?

Comment: @Jake: No, the `CASCADE` goes from `Friend` to `FriendsFoods` and `Food` to `FriendsFoods`.  Writing `tom.FriendsFoods.Remove(ff)` will not delete `tom`, nor will it delete the `pizza` entry.

Comment: Ok, so this works. Thanks! I was a little confused because I had the parent-child relationship backwards in my head, but now it all makes sense. I ended up setting the Delete Rule to Cascade in the SQL Server Management Studio designer, because I couldn't find anything relating to the delete rule in the LINQ-To-SQL designer.

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to delete the entry from the many-to-many table (`FriendFoods`) by removing it form the child collection of the linq entity, you'll need to set the `DeleteOnNull` attribute on the relationship equal to true in the dbml file. Unfortunately, you can't do it via the dbml designer. You have to open the .dbml file as an xml file and then manually edit the xml of the association.

See [How do I delete records from a child collection in LINQ to SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/900919/how-do-i-delete-records-from-a-child-collection-in-linq-to-sql)

Answer (score 2):

CASCADE DELETE does not apply here. It would only apply in the event that an entity is removed, either the Friend object or the Food object, but not if you simply want to delete the relationship.
Is there any reason you are not accessing the relational table directly? I think that would be a much cleaner solution.