# LINQ to SQL many to many relationship Insert and Delete problems

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, windows-phone-7, many-to-many

I'm trying to model the following relations using LINQ to SQL on Windows Phone 7.1:

```
create table x (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, text STRING);
create table y (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, text STRING);
create table z (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
                x_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                y_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
                FOREIGN KEY(x_id) REFERENCES x(id) ON DELETE CASCADE, 
                FOREIGN KEY(y_id) REFERENCES y(id) ON DELETE CASCADE);
```

So if I have a record in z table it should be deleted whenever I delete either the x record with id x_id or the y record with id y_id.

I have the following C# code (based on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286405(v=vs.92).aspx example):

```
namespace linq2sql.test.program
{
    public class MyDatabase : DataContext
    {
        public MyDatabase(string connectionString)
            : base(connectionString)
        { }

        public Table<X> Xs;
        public Table<Y> Ys;
        public Table<Z> Zs;
    }

    public class BaseTable : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
    {
        // boring interface implementation omitted for brevity
    }

    [Table]
    public class X : BaseTable
    {
        private int _id;
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, DbType = "INT NOT NULL Identity", CanBeNull = false, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
        public int Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set
            {
                if (_id != value)
                {
                    NotifyPropertyChanging("Id");
                    _id = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Id");
                }
            }
        }

        private EntitySet<Z> _zs;
        [Association(Storage = "_zs", OtherKey = "_xId", ThisKey = "Id", DeleteRule="CASCADE")]
        public EntitySet<Z> Zs
        {
            get { return this._zs; }
            set { this._zs.Assign(value); }
        }

        public X()
        {
            _zs = new EntitySet<Z>(
                new Action<Z>(this.attach_z),
                new Action<Z>(this.detach_z)
                );
        }

        private void attach_z(Z z)
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanging("Z");
            z.X = this;
        }

        private void detach_z(Z z)
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanging("Z");
            z.X = null;
        }
    }

    [Table]
    public class Y : BaseTable
    {
        // exactly the same as table X
    }

    [Table]
    public class Z : BaseTable
    {
        private int _id;
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, DbType = "INT NOT NULL Identity", CanBeNull = false, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
        public int Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set
            {
                if (_id != value)
                {
                    NotifyPropertyChanging("Id");
                    _id = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Id");
                }
            }
        }

        [Column]
        internal int _xId;

        private EntityRef<X> _x;
        [Association(Storage = "_x", ThisKey = "_xId", OtherKey = "Id", IsForeignKey = true)]
        public X X
        {
            get { return _x.Entity; }
            set
            {
                if (_x.Entity != value)
                {
                    NotifyPropertyChanging("X");
                    _x.Entity = value;

                    if (value != null)
                    {
                        _xId = value.Id;
                    }

                    NotifyPropertyChanged("X");
                }
            }
        }

        [Column]
        internal int _yId;

        private EntityRef<Y> _y;
        [Association(Storage = "_y", ThisKey = "_yId", OtherKey = "Id", IsForeignKey = true)]
        public Y Y
        {
            get { return _y.Entity; }
            set
            {
                if (_y.Entity != value)
                {
                    NotifyPropertyChanging("Y");
                    _y.Entity = value;

                    if (value != null)
                    {
                        _yId = value.Id;
                    }

                    NotifyPropertyChanged("Y");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I started to test it and run into two, probably related, problems. The following insertion code works:

```
using (MyDatabase db = new MyDatabase(KDBConnectionString))
{
    if (!db.DatabaseExists())
    {
        db.CreateDatabase();
    }

    X x = new X();
    db.Xs.InsertOnSubmit(x);

    Y y = new Y();
    db.Ys.InsertOnSubmit(y);

    Z z = new Z();
    x.Zs.Add(z);
    y.Zs.Add(z);
    db.SubmitChanges();

    Assert.IsTrue(db.Xs.Count() == 1, "no x");
    Assert.IsTrue(db.Ys.Count() == 1, "no y");
    Assert.IsTrue(db.Zs.Count() == 1, "no z");

    Assert.IsTrue(db.Xs.First().Zs.Count() == 1, "no z in x");
    Assert.IsTrue(db.Ys.First().Zs.Count() == 1, "no z in y");
}
```

But this code, which I expected to be equivalent, doesn't:

```
using (MyDatabase db = new MyDatabase(KDBConnectionString))
{
    if (!db.DatabaseExists())
    {
        db.CreateDatabase();
    }

    X x = new X();
    db.Xs.InsertOnSubmit(x);

    Y y = new Y();
    db.Ys.InsertOnSubmit(y);

    Z z = new Z() { X = x, Y = y };
    db.Zs.InsertOnSubmit(z);
    db.SubmitChanges();

    Assert.IsTrue(db.Xs.Count() == 1, "no x");
    Assert.IsTrue(db.Ys.Count() == 1, "no y");
    Assert.IsTrue(db.Zs.Count() == 1, "no z");

    Assert.IsTrue(db.Xs.First().Zs.Count() == 1, "no z in x"); // fails here
    Assert.IsTrue(db.Ys.First().Zs.Count() == 1, "no z in y");
}
```

Cascading delete doesn't work as I expected. This works:

```
using (MyDatabase db = new MyDatabase(KDBConnectionString))
{
    if (!db.DatabaseExists())
    {
        db.CreateDatabase();
    }

    X x = new X();
    db.Xs.InsertOnSubmit(x);

    Y y = new Y();
    db.Ys.InsertOnSubmit(y);

    Z z = new Z();
    x.Zs.Add(z);
    y.Zs.Add(z);
    db.SubmitChanges();

    db.Zs.DeleteOnSubmit(z);
    db.SubmitChanges();

    Assert.IsTrue(db.Zs.Count() == 0, "z not deleted");
    Assert.IsTrue(x.Zs.Count() == 0, "z not removed from x");
    Assert.IsTrue(y.Zs.Count() == 0, "z not removed from y");
}
```

This doesn't:

```
using (MyDatabase db = new MyDatabase(KDBConnectionString))
{
    if (!db.DatabaseExists())
    {
        db.CreateDatabase();
    }

    X x = new X();
    db.Xs.InsertOnSubmit(x);

    Y y = new Y();
    db.Ys.InsertOnSubmit(y);

    Z z = new Z();
    x.Zs.Add(z);
    y.Zs.Add(z);
    db.SubmitChanges();

    db.Xs.DeleteOnSubmit(x);
    db.SubmitChanges();

    Assert.IsTrue(db.Zs.Count() == 0, "z not deleted"); // ...this works, so "CASCADE" parameter has some effect
    Assert.IsTrue(y.Zs.Count() == 0, "z not removed from y"); // ... but fails here, so something is off
}
```

I suppose I have some simple mistake in foreign key definition, but I couldn't find it myself and my Google-Fu is weak today. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the insert issues, the example code with tests can be found here:

https://gist.github.com/1682648

The deletions are apparently not supported in a way I want. I've experimented with DeleteOnNull attribute, as suggested in answers to question [LINQ-To-SQL and Many-To-Many Relationship Deletions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569119/linq-to-sql-and-many-to-many-relationship-deletions), but it just doesn't work.